# Docker, Supervisord and supervisor-stdout

Tags: docker, supervisord

I'm trying to centralize output from supervisord and its processes using `supervisor-stdout`. But with this supervisord configuration:

```
#supervisord.conf

[supervisord]
nodaemon = true

[program:nginx]
command = /usr/sbin/nginx
stdout_events_enabled = true
stderr_events_enabled = true

[eventlistener:stdout]
command = supervisor_stdout
buffer_size = 100
events = PROCESS_LOG
result_handler = supervisor_stdout:event_handler
```

(Note that the config section of supervisor-stoud is exactly the same as the example on [the supervisor-stoud site](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/supervisor-stdout)).

...and this Dockerfile:

```
#Dockerfile

FROM python:3-onbuild

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y nginx supervisor

# Setup supervisord
RUN pip install supervisor-stdout
RUN mkdir -p /var/log/supervisor
COPY supervisord.conf /etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisord.conf
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

# restart nginx to load the config
RUN service nginx stop

# Start processes
CMD supervisord -c /etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisord.conf -n
```

I can build the image just fine, but running a container from it gives me:

> Error: supervisor_stdout:event_handler cannot be resolved within [eventlistener:stdout]

**EDIT**

The output from running:

> supervisord -c /etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisord.conf -n

is:

```
Error: supervisor_stdout:event_handler cannot be resolved within [eventlistener:stdout]
For help, use /usr/bin/supervisord -h
```

Comment: What is the output of ``supervisord -c /etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisord.conf -n`` when you run it manually within the container? Use: ``docker exec <cid> /bin/bash``

Comment: Added output from running `supervisord -c /etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisord.conf -n`

Comment: I don't see how/why you're getting the other error you reported in your question?

Comment: Sorry, pasted the wrong output. Duh. Fixed that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the exact same problem and solved it by using `Ubuntu 14.04` as a base image instead of `Debian Jessie` (I was using `python:2.7` image which is based on Jessie).

You can refer to this complete working implementation: https://github.com/rehabstudio/docker-gunicorn-nginx.

EDIT: as pointed out by @Vin-G in his comment, it might be because the supervisor version shipped with Debian Jessie is too old. You could try to remove it from apt and install it with pip instead.

Comment: That might work, but is a bit of an overkill, see my answer for the whys and the hows on fixing this

Answer (score 8):

I had the same problem, in short, you need to install the Python package that provides that `supervisor_stdout:event_handler` handler. You should be able to by issuing the following commands:

```
apt-get install -y python-pip
pip install supervisor-stdout
```

If you have `pip` installed on that container, a simple:

`pip install supervisor-stdout` should suffice, more info about that specific package can be found here:

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/supervisor-stdout

AFAIK, there is no debian package that provides the supervisor-stdout, so the easiest method to install it is through pip.

Hope it helps whoever comes here as I did.

[Edit]
As Vin-G suggested, if you still have a problem even after going through these steps, supervisord might be stuck in an old version. Try updating it.

Cheers!

Comment: I tried that, but it did not work. Also note that the original question states that `pip install supervisor-stdout` has been executed, and it does not solve the problem.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I'm puzzled, I had the same problem as you did, and that ```pip install supervisor-stdout``` did the trick.

If you still have the logs of the docker build to shed some light on the issue, great! If not, I'll just leave my answer here because this did it for me and it's rather cumbersome to change the whole container base image if you don't need to.

Comment: I've encountered the same problem @AlexandreBulté , (solution does not work even if the package was installed via pip). I believe what is wrong here is that the supervisord system package is too old of a version. To fix this, remove supervisor from apt-get install, then do pip install supervisor supervisor-stdout.

JoãoAntunes, you might want to edit your answer with that. I think that's what would solve op's problem

Comment: FWIW, this fixes it for me using ubuntu 14.04 latest image.

Comment: Is supervisor 3.2.0 considered "old" for this issue?

Comment: This works on Debian, thanks. BTW it doesn't work even on Debian 10 (Buster) without this

Answer (score 1):

Very similar to the above, but I don't think that there is a complete answer.

I had to remove from apt

```
apt-get remove supervisor
```

Then reinstall with pip, but with pip2 as the current version of supervisor doesn't support python 3

```
apt-get install -y python-pip
pip2 install supervisor
pip2 install supervisor-stdout
```

This all then worked.

Although the supervisord path is now

```
/usr/local/bin/supervisord
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

I used this hacky way to get it to work. It works in Debian Jessie as well.

I simply pasted the guy's [file](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/coderanger/supervisor-stdout/master/supervisor_stdout.py) to one of my own in my project directory. Like `/app/supervisord_stdout.py`

I then added it to the conf like this. `/app` is the project directory for my project files in the container.

```
[eventlistener:stdout]
command = python supervisord_stdout.py
buffer_size = 100
events = PROCESS_LOG
directory=/app
result_handler=supervisord_stdout:event_handler
environment=PYTHONPATH=/app
```